# mongodb Alerts for frequent queries

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-atlas

I have this query that inserts when a listener is listening to a song.

```
const nowplayingData = {"type":"S","station": req.params.stationname, "song": data[1], "artist": data[0], "timeplay":npdate};
                              LNowPlaying.findOneAndUpdate(
                                  nowplayingData,
                                  { $addToSet: { history: [uuid] } }, { upsert: true }, function(err) {
                                  if (err) {
                                      console.log('ERROR when submitting round');
                                      console.log(err);
                                  }
                              });
```

I have been getting the following emails for the last week - they are starting to get annoying.

[Mongodb Alerts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVnSA.png)

These alerts don't show anything wrong with the query or the code.

I also have the following query that checks for the latest userID matching the station name.

I believe this is the query setting off the alerts - because of the amount of times we request the same query over and over (runs every 10 seconds and may have unto 1000 people requesting the info at the same time.)

```
var query = LNowPlaying.findOne({"station":req.params.stationname, "history":{$in: [y]}}).sort({"_id":-1})
        query.exec(function (err, docs) {
            /*res.status(200).json({
                data: docs
             });*/
                console.error(docs)
                if(err){
                    console.error("error")
                    res.status(200).json(
                      err
                  );
                }
```

I am wondering how can I make this better so that I don't get the alerts - I know I either have to make an index works which I believe needs to be station name and history array.

I have tried to create a new index using the fields `station` and `history` But got this error

```
Index build failed: 6ed6d3f5-bd61-4d70-b8ea-c62d7a10d3ba: Collection AdStitchr.NowPlaying ( 8190d374-8f26-4c31-bcf7-de4d11803385 ) :: caused by :: Field 'history' of text index contains an array in document: { _id: ObjectId('5f102ab25b43e19dabb201f5'), artist: "Cobra Dukes", song: "Leave The Light On (Hook N Sling Remix) [nG]", station: "DRN1", timeplay: new Date(1594898580000), __v: 0, history: [ "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1OTQ5ODE0MjQsImlhdCI6MTU5NDg5NTAyNCwib2lkIjoicmFkaW9tZWRpYSJ9.ECVxBzAYZcpyueBP_Xlyncn41OgrezrOF8Dn3CdAnOU" ] }
```

Can you not index an Array?

How I am trying to create the index.
[my index creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4c6w.png)

Comment: In general, creating index(es) on the query filter fields helps with query performance (of update, find or delete operations). Yes, you can create index on an array field - these are called as Multikey indexes. So, how are you creating the index - include some details like the syntax used, information about any existing indexes involving the same fields, etc?

Comment: @prasad_ I am using compass app to make the index.

Comment: Include more details about how you are creating the index - the fields, options, index type, etc.

Comment: @prasad_ Please see the image @ https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4c6w.png

Comment: You are trying to create a _text index_ on `station`? What are these field types? You need to include a sample document in your post - also.

Comment: @prasad_ station is a text field. and history is a array

Comment: You can create an index on these two fields together - see the MongoDB documentation about creating a Compound Index. In the Compass the drop-down list box has Ascending, Descending, Text, etc., options. "Text" refers to a Text Index. You may want to change it to Asc or Desc. Are you trying to create a Text index?